# NextJS 13.3 Simple File upload using App directly and routes

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I'm really stuck. Can someone provide me with a really simple up to date using latest versions and features of NextJS 13.3 file upload to local storage code example?

I need a form with submit function that send api request to the APP/API/Routes (for example) and upload a file to the local server storage.

Thank you! A full simple working solution would be really appreciated.

I tried many examples but all are out-dated and not working.

Comment: Found a [newer guide here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-upload-and-download-file-to-api-in-next-js-application/), includes source code as well.  Are you using any third party service or just saving it to a file system? I'd also recommend you check out [Vercel Templates](https://www.vercel.com/templates).

Answer (score 6):

[Here's source code](https://github.com/hevi1991/nextjs-upload-to-local-example)

core code

```
// page.tsx

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-center p-24">
      <form action="/api/file" method="post" encType="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file" required />
        <button className="ring-2 px-3 py-2 bg-blue-800 text-white rounded-md">
          upload
        </button>
      </form>
    </main>
  );
}
```

and

```
// route.ts
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { existsSync } from "fs";
import fs from "fs/promises";
import path from "path";

export async function POST(req: NextRequest) {
  const formData = await req.formData();
  console.log(formData);

  const f = formData.get("file");

  if (!f) {
    return NextResponse.json({}, { status: 400 });
  }

  const file = f as File;
  console.log(`File name: ${file.name}`);
  console.log(`Content-Length: ${file.size}`);

  const destinationDirPath = path.join(process.cwd(), "public/upload");
  console.log(destinationDirPath);

  const fileArrayBuffer = await file.arrayBuffer();

  if (!existsSync(destinationDirPath)) {
    fs.mkdir(destinationDirPath, { recursive: true });
  }
  await fs.writeFile(
    path.join(destinationDirPath, file.name),
    Buffer.from(fileArrayBuffer)
  );

  return NextResponse.json({
    fileName: file.name,
    size: file.size,
    lastModified: new Date(file.lastModified),
  });
}
```

Comment: It is not allowing to req.formData(). Error formData is not a function.

Comment: Maybe you should check what kind of Next.js router system you are using and its version.

NextRequest extends the Web Request API with additional convenience methods.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/formData

Comment: You cant use public for save files, you will face problems in production like: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/16417